# If $r(t)$ lies on the circle of Radius R with centre O for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that $||r'|| = \sqrt {{-r''} \cdot {r}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

If $r(t)$ lies on the circle of Radius R with centre $O$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that $||r'|| = \sqrt {{-r''} \cdot {r}}$

I have been given a solution but I do not understand the first line.

Solution:

$r \cdot r = R^2$ => the dot product of 2 vectors is the radius of the circle squared?

So $0 = 2r \cdot r'$ => I understand because $R^2$ is a constant so the derivative is $0$ and $r \cdot r' + r' \cdot r = 2r \cdot r'$ because the dot product is commutative.

$=>0 = r \cdot r'$

differentiating again gives

$0 = r \cdot r'' + r' \cdot r'$

$||r'||^2 = -r \cdot r''$ because $r' \cdot r' = \sum_{i=1}^n r_{i}'^2 = ||r'||^2$

$||r'|| = \sqrt{-r'' \cdot r}$

So I understand all the mechanics of this proof and how to get to the final answer but it's just that first line: $r \cdot r = R^2$?

Comment: For all $t$, $\|r(t)\|=R$, so $r\cdot r=R^2$. That's assuming I'm reading the question correctly and the circle is centered at the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line applies only to a vector dotted with itself, not to two vectors more generally.

Recall
$$
a \cdot b = \|a\|\|b\|\cos\theta,
$$
so that
$$
r \cdot r = \|r\|^2\cos 0 = \|r\|^2 = R^2,
$$
because $\|r\| = R$.

Comment: Oh I see and the norm of r is the length of r (which should be equal to the radius from $O$ to the circle) and then you just square it

Comment: Yup, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r = (x,y,z)$ in Cartesian coordinates.
Then $r \cdot r = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$, since $R$ is the distance from $O=(0,0,0)$
to $r = (x,y,z)$.